# HTML Updating but Not Updating Visually

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a HTML game including JavaScript. There is an element by the id of `status` which includes `Current Turn: <span id="player">Player 1</span>`. I switch players with the following code.

```
if(player === 1) {
    player = 2;

    playerLabel.innerHTML = "Player 2"
    playerLabel.style.color = "blue";
}else {
    player = 1;

    playerLabel.innerHTML = "Player 1"
    playerLabel.style.color = "red";
}
```

Everything works fine until I have to reset the game with the following code.

```
player = 1;
marked = 0;
selectedRow = undefined;
win = false;

marks = [
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
    {isMarked: false},
];

statusLabel.innerHTML = "Current Turn: <span id=\"player\">Player 1</span>";
statusLabel.style.color = "black";
playerLabel.style.color = "red";
playerLabel.innerHTML = `Player 1`;

doneButton.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
doneButton.innerHTML = "You Must Mark At Least One Line";

for (var i = 0; i < gameButton.length; i++) {
    gameButton[i].classList.remove("red");
}
```

When the game resets, and when you switch turns, the player label never updates, although it says it does if I log the element in the console.

- `gameButton` is all the marks.
- `doneButton` is the button to switch turns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where comes the `playerLabel` variable in your code, but I'm pretty sure you're creating it at the init stage of your game and when you're doing `statusLabel.innerHTML = "Current Turn: <span id=\"player\">Player 1</span>";` you're creating a new `<span>` element, different from your previous `playerLabel`.

So, just after `statusLabel.style.color = "black";` try to re-assign `playerLabel` with `getElementById()` or whatever function you were using.

Comment: At the top of my code, I use `const playerLabel = document.getElementById("player");`

Comment: Works. Thanks for the help.